# Differentiability using differentiation

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

We use this method for piecewise functions to determine differentiability at the point where function changes its definition.
For example-

$f(x)$ =
\begin{cases}
x+1, & x<1 \\
2x^2, & x\geqslant 1
\end{cases}

First we check the continuity at the value of $x=1$. Then we calculate the limiting value of $f'(x)$ at $x=1$. If this value exists then we say that the function is differentiable otherwise not.
The idea of the method is quite obvious.

But my instructor said this method is not quite reliable. He said if the derivatives of the sides do not exist because limit of fluctuations then we should use the standard method. But I don't understand why? Can someone point out other flaws in this method as well?

Comment: Try a piecewise function $g$ defined by $g(x)=0$ when $x\leq0$ and $g$ is equal to Peter's function when $x>0.$  It still has $g'(0)=0$ but the right side limit of $g'$ does not exist.

Comment: @PeterForeman Perhaps you could make an answer with that example so Robin can accept it.

Comment: "Then we calculate the limiting value of $f'(x)$ at $x=1$. If this value exists then we say that the function is differentiable otherwise not." No, we do not say that. That condition is sufficient, but not necessary.

Comment: Well checking limit of $f'$ is about checking continuity of derivative and not existence of derivative. Credit should be deducted if the method is used in a typical exam. Also the method will not work if the limit of derivative does not exist.

Comment: For differentiability always use the definition : left and right hand derivatives should exist and be equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\le0\\x^2\sin{\left(\frac1x\right)}&x\gt0\end{cases}$$
Then we have
$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\le0\\2x\sin{\left(\frac1x\right)}-\cos{\left(\frac1x\right)}&x\gt0\end{cases}$$
Note that $\lim_{x\to0^-}f'(x)=0$ exists but $\lim_{x\to0^+}f'(x)$ doesn't exist. Although $f'(0)=0$ is defined by the typical definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

For a function $f$ to be differentiable at a point $x=a$ (assuming it is differentiable in the neighborhood of $a$ to begin with), 3 conditions must be met.

1: $f(a)$ exists.

2: $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a^-} f(x) $ and the limit is finite

3: $\lim_{x \to a^+} f'(x) = \lim_{x \to a^-} f'(x)$ and is again finite.

The function presented in this question fails criterion 3.

Comment: I am not asking for the given example. I am asking for the method in general

Comment: The method in general is use the definition.

Comment: Your third point is essentially the question here. It should be replaced by the equality of left and right hand derivative (similar to equality of left and right limit of a function for continuity).

Comment: Also why does one need to assume differentiability in some neighborhood of $a$? There are functions which are differentiable at just a single point.