# Even if f is an everywhere differential right function, it is still possible for f’ to be discontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Even if $f$ is an everywhere differential function, it is still possible for $f’$ to be discontinuous.
> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> x^2\sin\dfrac 1x, &x\ne 0\\
> 0, &x=0.
> \end{cases}$$
> According to theorem 7 $\ldots$

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a68qP.jpg)
Source. Page 203 of Calculus by Michael Spivak. However, I don’t know how to certify the function as differential nor how to prove its derivative as discontinuous. Basically, I don’t know how to analyze the function. Thank you so much for your time to help me.

Comment: I mentioned a very similar function in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3730277/631494) answer if it helps.

Comment: $x^2$ is everywhere differentiable. Product of two differentiable functions (let's say both are differentiable at a point $x=a$)  is differentiable at x=a. In your case, $sin(1/x)$ is problematic at $x=0$ elsewhere it is differentiable. So by definition of derivative: show that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$ exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is differentiable everywhere because: 
For all $x>0$ and for all $x<0$ the function is differentiable (The reason for this is that the composition of differentiable function is differentiable so $\sin(1/x)$ is differentiable as $\sin(x)$ is differentiable and $1/x$ is differentiable for $x>0$ and $x<0$ and then  you are just multiplying the function by a differentiable function and since product of differentiable functions is also differentiable it is true) 
 So $x^2\sin(1/x)$ is differentiable for all $x>0$ and $x<0$ .
 At zero the function is piece wise and to check it  is differentiable at $0$ you can  use the definition of the derivative and see if the limit exists.
 When you use the definition the limit  can be simplified to $$\lim_{h\to 0}  h\sin(1/h^2)$$ To prove this exists we can use the squeeze theorem  . (by using the fact $\sin(x)$ is bounded by $1$ and $-1$) and prove that it is $0$.

---

So we have proved that the function is differentiable everywhere we can compute its derivative to get $2\sin(1/x)x-\cos(1/x)$ for $x>0$ and $x<0$ and $0$ (from above ) for $x=0$ .
For this function to be continous at $0$ you need the limit as $x\to0$ is equal to $0$(the value of the function) however the limit does not exist because $\cos(1/x)$ keeps oscillating between $-1$  and $1$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Why the author then said, according to Theorem 7, however, the graph of f' can never exhibit a discontinuity of the type shown in Figure 22?